# Reading column data from a text file in python (custom spaces as delimiter)

Tags: python, dataframe

I am new to python and I am trying to read a space-delimited text file with spaces in the first column. The first row has to be eliminated and each of the 5 columns has to be read as a NumPy array (the scientific notation has to convert into a number). I already tried the `read_table` and `read_csv` functions of pandas but I get random results.  Any insight on this would really help me.

Thanks!

**My text data**
[image]

Comment: You can replace sequence of spaces with a single space with something like : `cat filename | tr -s " "`. read_csv should work afterwards.

Comment: How large is your file? Is reading it into memory a problem? (if not, the answer is fairly straightforward)

Comment: Also, you say you need it in a numpy array, but are mentioning pandas functions - which is it?

Comment: And finally, please put a sample of your data in the text, don't use images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need a dataframe as the tags suggest and not a numpy array as the text does. And assuming the whitespace shown in the image is nothing special, this should work just fine:

```py
from pandas import read_fwf

with open('file.txt') as f:
    next(f)
    df = read_fwf(f)

print(df)
```

The file is what is known as a 'fixed-width file' and that's exactly what `read_fwf` is for. The `next()` call just skips the header by reading and discarding one line from the file before passing it to `read_fwf()`.